# Use function to optimize code?

Tags: javascript, function

I Want to know how to optimize my code to get less lines overall.

I have the following :

```
for (var i = 0; i < meals; i++){
for (var x = 0; x < veggies.length; x++)
{
  rdm = Math.floor(Math.random()*veggies.length);
  var veggie = veggies[rdm]['name'];
  var veggieCal = vegPortion * veggies[rdm]["calories"];
  var veggieGrams = Math.floor((veggieCal * veggies[rdm]["weight"])/meals);
  console.log(veggieGrams);
}

for (var x = 0; x < carbs.length; x++)
{
  rdm = Math.floor(Math.random()*carbs.length);
  var carb = carbs[rdm]['name'];
  var carbCal = carbPortion * carbs[rdm]["calories"];
  var carbGrams = Math.floor((carbCal * carbs[rdm]["weight"])/meals);
  console.log(carbGrams);
}

for (var x = 0; x < proteins.length; x++)
{
  rdm = Math.floor(Math.random()*proteins.length);
  var protein = proteins[rdm]['name'];
  var protCal = protPortion * proteins[rdm]["calories"];
  var protGrams = Math.floor((protCal * proteins[rdm]["weight"])/meals);
  console.log(protGrams);
}

var ListItem = document.createElement("li");
var text= document.createTextNode(carbGrams+"g of "+carb+", "+veggieGrams+"g of "+veggie+" and "+protGrams+"g of "+protein);
ListItem.appendChild(text);
insdiv3.appendChild(ListItem);
```

}

As we can see my 3 for blocks are essentially the same. I want to write a function that gives the same syntax as my for where i use 5 parameters that i'll replace when calling the function like so :

```
  function rdmMeal(a,b,c,d,f)  {
for (var x = 0; x < a.length; x++)
{
  rdm = Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length);
  var b = a[rdm]['name'];
  var c = d * a[rdm]["calories"];
  var f = Math.floor((c * a[rdm]["weight"])/meals);
}
}
```

Where i can then just call the function and add my parameters :

```
//THIS IS WHAT I WANT MY CODE TO LOOK LIKE
for (var i = 0; i < meals; i++){
rdmMeal(veggies,veggie,veggieCal,vegPortion,veggieGrams);
rdmMeal(proteins,protein,protCal,protPortion,protGrams);
rdmMeal(carbs,carb,carbCal,carbPortion,carbGrams);}
```

Thus the parameters are replaced with my variables, essentially optimizing the code, how do i go about with this? Is what i wrote the right syntax or is there a different way i'm suppose to go with this?

Comment: `return` outside of the loop. Otherwise its fine.

Comment: Could you elaborate? (Very new to coding and not everything comes easily)

Comment: If you `return` inside the loop, the loop will only iterate over the first element, then it will return. I think thats not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to put these things in a loop, they always assign to the same variables. At best, those would qualify as `if (….length > 0)` statements, and we should assume that those are not necessary.

Next, please notice that variable names have absolutely no significance. You can name them anything you want, as long as every reference to the variable in its scope does use the same name. You also cannot pass variable names as parameters, you can only pass values. So the parameters `b`, `c` and `f` should be dropped from your function. Instead, use generic names that could refer to the calories of either veggies or proteins or carbs or anything, some for grams and item names.

Since you cannot assign to dynamically choosable outer-scope variables, you will  instead want to use return values from your function. You basically need the grams and the name. Since you cannot return two values, you will need to combine them inside the function. You could put them in an object that is returned, but since you are only going to put them in that string anyway you can do that immediately.

So your function should look like this:

```
function rdmMeal(categoryItems, portion)  {
  var rdm = Math.floor(Math.random() * categoryItems.length);
  var name = categoryItems[rdm].name;
  var calories = portion * categoryItems[rdm].calories;
  var grams = Math.floor((calories * categoryItems[rdm].weight)/meals);
  return grams+"g of "+name;
}
```

and you'd use it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < meals; i++) {
  var veggie = rdmMeal(veggies, vegPortion);
  var carb = rdmMeal(carbs, carbPortion);
  var protein = rdmMeal(proteins, protPortion);

  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  var text = document.createTextNode(carb+", "+veggie+" and "+protein);
  listItem.appendChild(text);
  insdiv3.appendChild(listItem);
}
```